# What could be wrong with this SQL syntax?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run an SQL query based on an answer I found for another question to update the table when the row exists, otherwise create the row:

```
UPDATE metric_target SET target1=1 WHERE userid=1

IF ROWCOUNT = 0 
   INSERT INTO metric_target (target2) VALUES (1);
```

When I run that query, I get the following error:

*1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ROWCOUNT = 0
   INSERT INTO metric_target (target2) VALUES (1)' at line 3*

Any idea what the problem could be? 
I'm using SQL Version 5.5.39

Comment: Try use a variable @updates = (SELECT ROW_COUNT());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `user_id` is your unique index, then its better to do `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`

Something like that

```
   INSERT INTO metric_target (userid, target2) VALUES (1, 1)
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE target2=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE metric_target SET target1=1 WHERE userid=1;
IF (ROW_COUNT() = 0) THEN
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO metric_target (target2) VALUES (1);
END;
END IF;
```

Comment: I just copied and pasted that directly in and get this error : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 THEN
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO metric_target (target2) VALUES (1' at line 1

Comment: Yep, I copied that answer directly including with the semi colon after userid=1

Comment: I'm not sure phpmyadmin allows to run multiple queries with relation. I mean - you can put multiple queries in this window, but they will be treated unrelated. If I'm write `ROW_COUNT()` will give nothing, so it throws an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72781/discussion-between-cyadvert-and-flodorhlod).

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be a function...try this

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0